# Should I provide these things by default or only on client request

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, accessibility

Should I provide these things by default or only on client request (if they are paying for these)

- Try to implement graceful degradation
  on JavaScript
- Print css
- Handheld CSS
- Form validation
- Combine all CSS and JS into one if possible and minified them
- XML Site-map
- Skip to main content link
- Fluid layout
- make Abbr ,Acronym if possible
- Tabindex
- Accesskey
- Shorthand CSS
- Site testing in all browsers

All things takes time.

Should we consider about

- User who will take print
- User with javascript disabled
- Small screen users
- SEO
- Usability on forms
- Screen reader users

If client nothing said about these.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like you want us to prioritise your work. Do you want to deny your users something that will improve your site?

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki or something? Certainly not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, your work speaks volumes about *you* as a person. If you short-change your customers, others will see, and will reconsider hiring you.

The minimum ought to be a fully-functional site that renders properly on the primary browsers. Having print-ready CSS is nice, but I wouldn't spend too much time on it unless the client requested it. Regarding "skip to content" links - if you need one of those, you may want to reconsider your design; users shouldn't have to hunt down your content.

Comment: u mean i should give quality without asking extra money.

Comment: @Jitendra: You should give them something you're proud of.

Comment: @DN is correct. You shouldn't consider "quality" as an addon-service to your work. It should be the heart of all that you do.

Comment: @ Jonathan Sampson - This is Right but should i try to make every site perfect even if client is not paying for my time.

Comment: @Jitendra: Don't waste your time with cheap clients. Let them know that you do quality work, and you charge appropriate rates. If they complain, let them go.

Comment: @Jitendra: I've spent days working on free/charity work before, knowing that although I'm not getting paid for it, it will be representing me and my work to potential clients in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should charge for your time.  The contract should enumerate all substantial items so the client knows where your time is spent.  They should have the option to choose to leave things out if it's not important to them, hopefully taking your advice as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. If you are making a "from scratch" design to sell to people, the more the better. If you are working for a single client, then all specifications should at the very least be agreed upon in the beginning, and worked into the costing.

All the above can be implemented as features down the track as well, however a few things I would do anyway are the following, as these are functional, and some very important:

- Print CSS
- Form validation **
- XML Site Map
- No-Script Tags **

** Important to implement these in my opinion